# How to properly size images within a div using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image

[this is how I want the final organization to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzfIN.png)I have two images and some text, I cannot sort out how to properly situate them so that the image on the left is smaller and also so that the entire div moves with my page when it's scaled up and down

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- ------------------------------ Section 1 ------------------------------ -->
                    <section class="sec-1">
                                <img class="img-1" src="./images/image-1.jpeg" alt="blue van driving on a highway at the base of a mountain.">
                                <div class="feature-box-1">
                                    <img class="img-2" src="./images/image-2.jpeg" alt= "small row boat, aerial view, large body of water.">
                                
                                    <h4>FEATURE</h4>
                                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h2>
                                    <a class="button" href="#">read more</a>
                                </div>
                    </section>
```

CSS:

```
   /* -------------------------------- Section 1 ------------------------------- */
    
    .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 85%;
    
}
    .sec-1 {
        border: 5px solid red;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 125px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    .feature-box-1 {
        background:#F6F8FA;
        margin-left: 35px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .img-1 {
        max-height: 650px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .img-2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .sec-1 h4 {
        color: #777777;
    }
    
    .sec-1 h2 {
        font-size: 39px;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand what you trying to do, it means you need to define a min-witdh for the image on the left. when there is not enough place to show the image it will get down the text. Am I right? is it what you're trying to do?

Comment: @IsraGab yes, the image on the left seems to be defining the size of the div its in, which leaves too much neg space under the text on the right side, under the row boat image.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You just need to put them in containers for example .aside-left .aside-right   and inside .aside-right you can add container .top and  .bottom

```
<style>
    /* -------------------------------- Section 1 ------------------------------- */

    .container {
        display: flex;
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .aside-left {
        display: flex;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .aside-right {
        margin-left: 2%;
        width: 68%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .aside-left img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .aside-right .top {
        width: 100%;
        height: 45%;
    }

    .aside-right .bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 55%;
    }

    .sec-1 h4 {
        color: #777777;
    }

    .sec-1 h2 {
        font-size: 39px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <!-- ------------------------------ Section 1 ------------------------------ -->
    <section class="aside-left">
        <img class="img-1" src="" alt="blue van driving on a highway at the base of a mountain.">
    </section>
    <section class="aside-right">
        <div class="top">
            <img class="img-2" src="./images/image-2.jpeg" alt="small row boat, aerial view, large body of water.">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <h4>FEATURE</h4>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h2>
            <a class="button" href="#">read more</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```